# What directories should I back up?

Tags: linux-mint, backup

In this question, [Accidentally deleted /usr/share](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1139069/accidentally-deleted-the-usr-share-folder) a comment says that:

> many user programs store application data there

Currently, I only back-up my `/home` directory tree; including hidden files and directories, since that is where I would expect configuration data to be stored.

Should I back up `/usr/share` also? I did `ls -ltr /usr/share` and was surprised to find sub-directories that had been modified recently, when I had not installed anything, or even used `sudo`. Sudo is important because I don't have write access to `/usr/share` directory.

Finally, are there any other similar directories that I should back up? (By similar, I mean being modified unexpectedly.)

Comment: step0: do not execute any commands that you don't know the result. next step(s): backup your import data, all other data are always replaceable

Answer (score 2):

System configuration data are stored in `/etc` and `/var`, generally. `/usr/share` holds package files. You are probably seeing recent modifications due to package upgrades.

If you expect to be able to recreate your system on another machine, you will want to start with the list of installed packages. You can get this with `dpkg --get-selections` (There are other methods, but this is simple. You simply save the output in a file and later you can pass it back to `dpkg --set-selections`. You lose information about which packages were automatically installed but at least you have a working system). These lists are stored in `/var`, but a text file is easier to back up than a potentially inconsistent database file.

`/var/lib` and `/var/backups` will also help you to recover your system.

Unless you have made local changes, most of `/etc` is provided by installed packages. You may want to back up `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` so that users can log in after recovery, but if you have to rebuild a single-user system from scratch this isn't important. `/etc/default` stores configuration data for installed packages.